# no video software will display source timestamp on Windows even though QuickTime Player on Mac displays for same mp4 files

Tags: windows, timestamp, video-processing

I am watching mp4 video files from gopro videos that I took. I need the time stamps on the video software to display the actual recorded time (source timestamp) of when the gopro was recording the video in order to know exactly what happened when (e.g. I need to go to 10:11:12:15 on 06/11/2023 in the video to see what happened at that millisecond). For some reason, I cannot find any video software that will display the actual source timestamp on any software compatible with Windows. They only display time stamps associated with the length of the video file. However, when I use QuickTime Player on a Mac, the source timestamp is displayed there. I even tried the QuickTime Player for Windows, but that version will not display it either.

Has anyone found free video software for a Windows that will display that? Here are some video software that I have tried so far but couldn't get to work: VLC, Pot Player, GOM player, VideoPad, OpenShot, etc.